# Close ONLY Excel processes opened by UFT

Tags: excel, vbscript, hp-uft

I have a UFT script, which upon execution, opens a lot of Excel workbooks. (I can see it in the Task Manager). How can I close only the Excel files that are opened by UFT alone (temp workbooks) and not the workbooks opened by me?

If this can be done using VBScript, it would be more helpful.

Comment: Open files using `Set x = GetObject("Filename.xls","")`

Comment: Excel.Application.Workbooks.Close?

Comment: workbooks.close closes all the excels. I want to close only the excels which are not visible.

Comment: How do your scripts open the workbooks?

Comment: set objWorkbook = objExcel.WorkBooks.Open(strRunOrder,,True)..This is the line used to open the workbooks

Comment: `objWorkbook.Close`

Comment: did you try SystemUtil.CloseDescendentProcesses ? this closes all process opened by UFT

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I think you should post that as an answer, since it seems to be exactly what shilpa is looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
Function close_workbook_by_name(workbookname)
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")
    For Each x In xl.Application.Workbooks
        If x.Name = workbookname Then
            x.Close
        End If
    Next
    Set xl = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open the workbooks like you said:

```
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.WorkBooks.Open(strRunOrder, , True)
```

you should be able to close them by simply calling the `Close` method on the variable storing the workbook object:

```
objWorkbook.Close
```

If you're opening multiple workbooks at the same time and want to close them at some later point you need to keep tabs on all of them, e.g. by storing the handles in a dictionary or array.